# Map of <int, bool> in C++ defaults to false

Tags: c++, data-structures, c++14, std

I want to insert custom values to my map, which is happening in the first part of the code but not in the second snippet. My code is below:

```
// First part of the code

unordered_map<int, int> hashmap;

for(int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++)
{
    if(hashmap.find(arr[i]) != hashmap.end())
        hashmap[arr[i]] += 1;
    hashmap.insert(make_pair(arr[i], 1));
}

// Second part of the code

unordered_map<int, bool> hash2;
    
for(auto it=hashmap.begin(); it != hashmap.end(); ++it)
{
    if(hash2[it->second] == true)
        return false;
    hash2.insert(make_pair(it->second, true));
}
return true;
```

When I try to create a custom map (key-value pair) and set the 'value' to 1 it is working but when I try to create a custom map in the second part of the code it defaults to `false`.

Can anyone help me debug this issue?

Comment: Note: in the first loop, if `find()` succeeds, the element is incremented and the subsequent `insert()` fails. If `find()` fails, the increment is skipped, and the `insert()` succeeds. You are missing an `else`, eg: `for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i) { if (hashmap.find(arr[i]) != hashmap.end()) { hashmap[arr[i]] += 1; } else { hashmap.insert(make_pair(arr[i], 1)); } }` In which case, you can simplify it to just: `for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i) { hashmap[arr[i]]++; }` Letting the map set newly inserted elements to 0 before returning them for incrementing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at the second part:

```cpp
unordered_map<int, bool> hash2;

for(auto it=hashmap.begin(); it != hashmap.end(); ++it)
{
    if(hash2[it->second] == true)                    // 1, 2
        return false;
    hash2.insert(make_pair(it->second, true));       // 3
}
return true;                                         // 4
```

1. `hash2[it->second]` will insert a `bool{}` (`false`) since the *Key* doesn't exist in the map the first time the value of `it->second` is used in this lookup. If the same value is used to do another lookup later in the loop, it'll return a reference to the *Value* stored for the *Key* (and the *Value* will be `false` until changed).
2. `hash2[it->second]` returns a reference to the inserted `bool` and compares `==` it with `true`. Since the `bool` stored in *1.* is `false`, this comparison will always be `false`, so it will never `return false;`
3. Here it tries to `insert` a pair with the same *Key* as used above, but with the mapped *Value* `true`. This `insert`ion always fails since the *Key* already exists in the map.
4. The loop continues until its finished and then the function returns `true`.

Comment: Thanks @Ted Lyngmo. I understood my mistake. Actually, I am trying to create another hashmap using the values of the first check its uniqueness. I know this can be achieved using a `set` but I wanted to try this approach as well.

Comment: @VatsalAggarwal You're welcome! Sure, you can create another hashmap if you'd like. I'm not 100% sure what you actually wanted to do with `if(hash2[it->second] == true)` though and you don't actually need a map or `set` to check if the values you used to populate the first hashmap where all unique. You could simply `return false` directly when inserting in the first map. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/78asTsKTs) - or with a [_range-based `for` loop_](https://godbolt.org/z/7TdYqh7hT) to make it clearer

Comment: So I need to make sure that the 'frequencies' of each element are unique. So for that, I need the first hashmap as is. Then I was trying to build another hashmap for those frequencies in the first hashmap.

Comment: Aha, the counts should be unique.  [Like this?](https://godbolt.org/z/4j5xT8aeo) It doesn't return directly when a non-unique count is found, but you'll probably figure out where to insert a `return false;` there :-)

Comment: Yep, that is exactly what I was looking for and yeah I modified my code after your answer to get the intended result.

Comment: @VatsalAggarwal Great! A simplification could be to _count-the-counts_ instead of storing `bool`s. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/j11P4KTes)